# How can I list all files of a directory more simpler in GJS

Tags: gnome-shell, gjs

Now i can use `Gio.File.new_for_path` `Gio.File.enumerate_children` `Gio.FileEnumerator.next_file` to list all files in directory. But It's too heavy to bring out all attributes of all files, I only need put filenames into an array.

I want more simpler mothed, like GLib do. But `g_dir_open` `g_dir_read_name` not in the gjs library of https://gjs-docs.gnome.org.

The GLib here like a reduced version? Any advise? thanks.

Comment: `g_dir_open` is marked as non-introspectable in the GIR file. So you can only use `Gio` at the moment.